# Extremely thin line between `SliverAppBar` and `SliverPersistentHeader` in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, sliverappbar, flutter-sliverappbar

So I am using a `CustomScrollView` and inside I have `SliverAppBar` and `SliverPersistentHeader` as the first two children, with no styling except blue background color.

But there is a really faint, translucent (because when I scroll I can see that there is something behind this line) thin line between them. Is there any way to remove it or make it look like there is no such line. As you can see here

[image]

I have tried everything: removing any styling, changing background color, but nothing worked.

**Note:** I have to use these two, I can't use the `bottom` of the `SliverAppBar`.

Comment: you cannot do that without any dirty hacks, why don't you use single sliver persistent header? notice that sliver app bar is a persistent header anyway (just take a look into the sources)

Comment: @pskink Well, I have made a custom complicated `SliverAppBar` class. I don't want to add anything to it, because the animations and stuff will break, because it is a messy implementation, which takes into account the appBar's height, etc. Because of that, I would like the content of the `SliverPersistentHeader` to be a seperate implementation

Comment: Share your code here, if possible!